# build-extras.gradle - overwrite or merge?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have been advised to use `build-extras.gradle` opposed to editing a generated `build.gradle` file if I want to make edits to the gradle settings.

This is fine. But I would like to know if the settings in `build-extras.gradle` overwrite the settings in `build.gradle`, or do they merge with settings in `build.gradle`.

E.g. if I have the following build.gradle file:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                'myApp' + manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile) + "_"
                    + getDate() + '.apk'
            )
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
```

If I had the following in `build-extras.gradle`:

```
android {
    lintOptions: {
        checkDebugBuilds: false
    }
}
```

Will that essentially overwrite the option `checkReleaseBuilds` since `build-extras.gradle`, or will it merge the two?

The reason I ask, is because I am trying to determine which of the following is needed for a `build-extras.gradle`:

A:

```
android {
    lintOptions: {
        checkDebugBuilds: false
    }
}
```

B:

```
android {
    lintOptions: {
        checkDebugBuilds: false
        checkReleaseBuilds: true
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Formatted file names to make them easier to read.

Comment: Did you find out how these files are merged?

Comment: @AndreKreienbring - not yet :( I haven't investigated further. I will let you know when I know.